# What are the murthis allowed in one's puja mandir?

Tags: worship, puja, idols

It is said that the size of an idol should not be more than a thumb size of the family's head. If there is not a special puja/worship, nivedya/food offerings should be offered to the murthi/idol daily, is this true?

Why are shila/rock murthi not prominently used in inhouse worship? Likewise, can someone tell what is the best among murthi made of panchaloha, gold, silver, rock, sand and picture/illusion?